# Script in Startup Applications Not Running in Ubuntu 18.10, but was in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: bash, startup-applications

I have a script to run a cloud syncing tool that I would like to run at startup.

The script lives in /home/jasper/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive_startup.sh

```
:~$ ls -l /home/jasper/.odrive-agent/bin/
total 16904
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jasper jasper  6461090 Nov  8 17:37 odrive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jasper jasper 10781297 Nov  8 17:37 odriveagent
-rw-r--r-- 1 jasper jasper    54683 Mar 26 13:51 odrive.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jasper jasper       79 Mar 27 11:19 odrive_startup.sh
```

and reads as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup odriveagent > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

In case anyone is interest $HOME expands to

```
:~$ echo $HOME
/home/jasper
```

And this is added to my path

```
export PATH="/home/jasper/.odrive-agent/bin:$PATH"
```

I tried using the Startup Applications GUI to run this script at startup

[image]

but always find the executable is not running at startup. Running the script itself from the terminal does work however.

Another oddity is that this same method was working in Linux Mint 19.1, but does not work in Ubuntu 18.10.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this method work, figure out what is preventing this executable from being run or have a different method to start odriveagent at startup? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just auto-starting `odriveagent` directly? Why do you need a script in the first place?

Comment: In my experience Startup Applications needs a script?

Comment: It does? I don’t know for sure, but it reads “Command”… Worth a try. :)

Comment: Putting nohup odriveagent > /dev/null 2>&1 & in the command field did not work.

Comment: you don’t really need anything except `odriveagent` there – if just that doesn’t work there’s something odd going on.

Comment: That also didn't work.

Comment: Is there anyway to see if an error message was logged when the attempt to run the program was made? Also, everything I have tried with Startup Applications so far  works when I just run it in the terminal.

Comment: redirect output of command to see log: ...odriveagent >/tmp/mylog 2>&1

Comment: Tested with the script calling the executable from the PATH and giving the exact path: nohup odriveagent > /tmp/mylog 2>&1 yields
nohup: failed to run command 'odriveagent': No such file or directory and nohup “$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odriveagent” > /dev/null 2>&1 & yields nohup: failed to run command '“/home/jasper/.odrive-agent/bin/odriveagent”': No such file or directory

Comment: Try adding `/full/path/to/odriveagent` as the startup command or specify the absolute path in the script if you want to use that.

Comment: Did you try it using the absolute path?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the late response. It did work with the full path in the script and giving the full path to the script to the Startup Applications program. I still don't understand why $HOME doesn't work because echo $HOME returns "/home/jasper"... I solved my problem I guess, but am not satisfied haha